# Testing variables against one another in a linear model (F-test)

Tags: self-study, anova, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to solve the Q1 of the following sheet: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~nicholls/sb1a/SB1_15class2.pdf

but I really don't understand how this stuff works. I think I've stumbled through part (a), here are my thoughts for part (b):

We want to test the model $H_0: y \sim 1 + \mathrm{History}$ against $H_1: y \sim 1 + \mathrm{History} + \mathrm{Treatment \ E}$. I think we need to use an F-test because we're dropping a bunch of Treatment variables, but I'm not sure how to calculate the F-statistic under the two different hypotheses. I don't quite understand how to work out the RSS under each different model (in order to compute the F-statistic). Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the self-study tag since this is homework.

Comment: Please copy whatever context is necessary to understand your question into the body of the question. People aren't going to want to download & read something to answer your question, & we want this Q to continue to have value after that link goes dead.